# Can't connect to Firebase - Need to resolve app gradle issues

Tags: android, firebase

I am getting the following error when trying to connect to Firebase (If it matters it's specifically Firebase Authentication):

> Could not parse the Android Application Module's Gradle config. Resolve gradle build issues and/or resync.

*Gradle syncs without errors btw.

This is how my app gradle dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:+'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-nearby:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:4.1.0'
 }
```

Comment: Replace all `compile` with `implementation` and sync the project

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, you should replace `compile` to `implementation` and then press the Sync project button.

Note this :

> The compile configuration still exists but should not be used as it will not offer the guarantees that the api and implementation configurations provide.

Answer (score 2):

I was faced with the same problem but at least I managed to resolve it and the Best way to resolve this problem is to update the following dependencies to the ones.

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same problem but at least I managed to resolve it and the Best Way:

Please Make Changes in Application Module's Gradle config:

1. In Android: compileSdk 31   ---Change Your SDK Version Like in My Project I use 31
2. After compileOptions{} you add this :

compileSdkVersion 31 ---Add this code in your
buildToolsVersion '30.0.3'  ---Add this code in your

3. In dependencies add this:

implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.2'    ---Change Your dependencies

Now Sync Your Project Firebase Console will be open……

Answer (score -1):

I was only trying to set up Firebase Test Lab for my app, so I actually didn't need to connect my app to Firebase.

I ended up skipping the Connect to Firebase step and jumping to Step 4, *Run app tests in the cloud*, and it worked perfectly.